# angular 2 named router-outlet not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I using named router-outlet to render some component data. This named router-outlet is in `app component` with main router-outlet.

Here is my outlet:

```
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

Here is my route-config:

```
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'contact-list', component: ContactlistComponent },
  { path: 'contact-hold/:id', component: ContactOperationComponent, outlet: 'popup' },
```

and here is my link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['\',{outlets:{popup:['hold',1]}}]">Hold</a>
```

[image: route debugger image]

It worked when i changed my route config. But now new problem is coming i cant get passed parameter to my aux url.

here i am trying to get parameter from router in my hold component:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=> {      
      console.log(params["id"]);
    })
```

Comment: you try to like this [routerLink]="['/contact', { outlets: { popup: ['hold'] } }]"

Comment: I have tried that too still it creates URL like this `contact/(list//popup:hold/1)` which is not acceptable. thanks for the ans.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so can you please share with us on how you solve it

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3346-named-outlets-require-non-empty-parent-route-segment-paths-in-angular-4-4-4.htm) that might help

Answer (score -1):

This is my Sample code for related your question :

before you open popup. The url is like image shown below

[image]

**component.html**

```
<button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { popup: 'product-family/'+ productFamily.id + '/delete'} }]" replaceUrl="true" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
<span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
<span class="hidden-md-down">Delete</span>
```

**route.ts**

```
export const productFamilyPopupRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'product-family/:id/delete',
        component: ProductFamilyDeletePopupComponent,
        outlet: 'popup'
    }
];
```

After Click Delete button the url will be changed show below image:

[image]

Comment: [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { popup: 'hold'} }]"  in route.ts path: 'hold'

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but by doing this i am getting same error **Cannot match any routes**.

Comment: and there is a **#** in your url is it just `<a> tag href` thing or it means something here. And also whats is products in your url is it a parent route?